# I'm a new programmer and I'm trying to get this code to work, but I can't seem to get the variables x, y and z to be bound

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

```
price_apple = 1.00
price_pear = 1.50
apple_stock = 50
pear_stock = 30
totalstock = apple_stock + pear_stock
while totalstock != 0:
  totalstock = apple_stock + pear_stock
  if totalstock == 0:
    print("Sadly we don't have any more fruit in stock.")
    break
  order = input("What would you like to order? ")
  if order == "apples":
    x, y, z = apple_stock, price_apple, "apples"      
  elif order == "pears":
    x, y, z = pear_stock, price_pear, "pears" 
  if order == "apples" or order == "pears" and totalstock > 0:
    number = list(map(int,input("How many would you like to order? ").strip().split()))
    for individual_order in number:
      if x >= individual_order:
        x = x - individual_order
        print(order, )
        print("You have enough", z, "in stock")
        print("Your total price is", str(order * x))
        print("Your", z, "stock is now", x, z)
      else:
        break
  if order != "apples" and order != "pears":*
    break
```

I want either the if or the elif to continue on these next lines of code, but the variables aren't bound.

This is the error message I get from my original code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/runner/School-project/mail.py", line 134, in <module>
        if order == "apples" and x == 0:
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I tried putting the code under the variables like this, and it works, but I don't want a huge code     (this is a small and simplified part of my code) This would also make the variables useless.

```
  #code
  order = input("What would you like to order? ")
  if order == "apples":
    x, y, z = apple_stock, price_apple, "apples"
    if order == "apples" and totalstock > 0:
      number = list(map(int,input("How many would you like to order? ").strip().split()))
      for individual_order in number:
        if x >= individual_order:
          x = x - individual_order
          print(order, )
          print("You have enough", z, "in stock")
          print("Your total price is", str(order * x))
          print("Your", z, "stock is now", x, z)
  elif order == "pears":
    x, y, z = pear_stock, price_pear, "pears"
    number = list(map(int,input("How many would you like to order? ").strip().split()))
    for individual_order in number:
      if x >= individual_order:
        x = x - individual_order
        print(order, )
        print("You have enough", z, "in stock")
        print("Your total price is", str(order * x))
        print("Your", z, "stock is now", x, z)
```

It would be really nice to have this fixed, I would go from close to 900 lines to around 250

Comment: Ignore the **, I put them there by accident while typing this question.

Comment: you can also edit the original question to fix typos

Comment: It would be very helpful if you also add the exact error message and the whole traceback.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know

Comment: It doesn't look like you have an `else` branch. What do you expect to happen when the order doesn't match "pears" or "apples"? How sure are you that *isn't the problem you're having right now*?

Comment: I edited to remove the `**` and also brought the first two code blocks into a single block since I believe that was the intent. @Jack please feel free to edit if that was not your intent.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or are you just trying to refactor an existing code?

Comment: I agree with Jared Smith that missing else clause is likely the problem. On another note, you can enforce a specific user input to avoid having unpredictable values for order. For example like this:

    order = ""
    while order not in ["apples", "pears"]:
        order = input("Please order apples or pears")

Comment: Please provide a [mre], I don't see any line which contains the following in the code you share: `if order == "apples" and x == 0:`

Comment: You could just set x, y, and z to a default `x,y,z = 0, 0, 'none'` where you set the rest of the variables, as an option.

Comment: It's worth noting that using variables like `x`, `y`, and `z` as substitutes for others only makes your code more confusing, it doesn't help here, and you should really just use the original names. What you really need to do here is use *data structures* instead of independent variables, and also think about using functions more. `{ price: 1.5, stock: 2, name: "Pear" }` is a lot easier to work with than `pear_price` and such. Put those in an array, or in a `dict` indexed by name and you have a simple "database".

Comment: @JaredSmith I have the else branch in my code, I didn't include it here because it didn't cause the issue.

Comment: @Jack a) how do you know that? and b) why would you expect us to intuit that since you didn't show us and a missing else clause would be a likely source of those variables not being bound?

Comment: The error message says this is the problematic line of code: `if order == "apples" and x == 0:`; however this does not appear anywhere in the code you pasted as your "original" code, so it seems the code you are running and the code you have asked for help with are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little demo I wrote for you, try to structure your code better.

here is a loopable code, which also keeps the state in memory, its highly dynamic

```py
inventory = {
    'apple': {
        'total': 50,
        'price': 1.00
    },
    'pear': {
        'total': 30,
        'price': 1.50
    },
}

currentItem = ""
currentAmount = 0

while True:
    print("======================================")
    print("==              Menu                ==")
    print("======================================")
    for key in inventory.keys():
        line = "==  {name} -> {items_total} @ ${price} each".format(name=key, items_total = inventory[key]['total'], price = inventory[key]['price'])
        print(line + ( " " * (36 - len(line))) + "==")
    print("======================================")
    currentItem = input("What would you like to order? ")
    if currentItem not in inventory.keys():
        print("Invalid Item Selected")
        continue
    currentAmount = int(input("How many would you like? "))
    if currentAmount <= 0:
        print("Invalid Amount Entered, Value to low")
        continue
    if currentAmount > inventory[currentItem]['total']:
        print("Invalid Amount Entered, Value to high")
        continue
    inventory[currentItem]['total'] = inventory[currentItem]['total'] - currentAmount
    purchasedPriceAmount = inventory[currentItem]['price'] * currentAmount
    print("You have purchased {amount} {name}s for ${price} each".format(amount=currentAmount, name=currentItem, price=inventory[currentItem]['price']))
    print("With a total of ${totalPrice}".format(totalPrice=purchasedPriceAmount))
```

## Example run

Tested code at [Programiz Python Online Compiler](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/)

[image]

Comment: @Jack you could also modify this to include a way to exit gracefully and also an option to load the menu aka "inventory" from file. (saving and loading)

Comment: once you do that, you can then add a database, to handle storing and editing the inventory

Comment: why do you need an image to show some text output

Comment: why not use a `class Item`

Comment: @rioV8 wanted to keep it simple. I prefer taking images of output

Comment: now you need 2 variables to keep track of the `name` and the `total`, 2 places to get things wrong

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Ah, thanks so much, this is very close to what I eventually want!

Comment: Why vote to close a question, then go on to answer it? Should you not do one or the other?

Comment: @JonSG voted closed, but then decided to answer as OP was a noob and needed proper help

Comment: @rioV8 yes, that is the state variables, which is globally used.